# How to get value under <ol> <li> using scrapy spider python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm web crawler newbie and just followed this article. It's pretty easy to follow.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3

And I have 1 website target to do it. The purpose is to get a product price and name list under class **ais-Hits-list**.

For example --> price (**259**) and name (**XT7 women's trail running shoes dark blue and pink**)

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="search-suggestions-algolia" style="display:none">
        <div>
            <div class="ais-Hits">
                <ol class="ais-Hits-list">
                    <li class="ais-Hits-item"></li>
                    <li class="ais-Hits-item"></li>
                    <li class="ais-Hits-item"></li>
                    <li class="ais-Hits-item"></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="wrapper">
    <div id="#content" class="site-content shop-grid">
        <div id="">
            <div id="js-product-list">
                <div class="products product_content" id="hits">
                    <div>
                        <div class="ais-Hits">
                            <ol class="ais-Hits-list">
                                <li class="ais-Hits-item">...</li>
                                <li class="ais-Hits-item">...</li>
                                <li class="ais-Hits-item">
                                    <div class="price-button">
                                        <a class="algolia_link" href="/p/8552163_xt7-women-s-trail-running-shoes-dark-blue-and-pink.html">
                                            <div class="product_price">
                                                <button class="is-skewed" itemprop="price">259</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_name">
                                                <h4 class="title-single" title="XT7 women's trail running shoes dark blue and pink"></h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="product-flags"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="ais-Hits-item">...</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my code is

```
# scrapy runspider scraper.py
import scrapy
import json

class xxxx(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xxxx_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.xxxx.co.id/8548777-running-shoes']
    allowed_domains = ['xxxx.co.id']


    def parse(self, response):

        PRODUCT_SELECTOR = '#js-product-list .product_content .ais-Hits .ais-Hits-list .ais-Hits-item'

        for item in response.css(PRODUCT_SELECTOR):
            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h4 ::attr(title)'
            PRICE_SELECTOR = 'button ::text'

            yield {
                'name': item.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'price': item.css(PRICE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            }
```

But it always returns nothing. Is there any part that I was missing?

```
2019-12-11 18:16:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-11 18:16:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-11 18:16:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-11 18:16:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.xxxx.co.id/8548777-running-shoes> (referer: None)
[]
2019-12-11 18:16:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-11 18:16:42 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 236,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 29492,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.876863,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 11, 10, 16, 42, 734103),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 11, 10, 16, 39, 857240)}
2019-12-11 18:16:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

This website has 2 classes for ais-Hits-item (header and section).

The reason I didn't put `PRODUCT_SELECTOR='.ais-Hits-item'`, it because it will direct to ais-Hits-item header, not the section one.

Comment: Could you also share the link of the page that you would like to crawl?

Comment: https://www.decathlon.my/8548777-running-shoes @Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this page is being rendered by Javascript.
You can see in the network tab of your browser that it is making a post request to retrieve the data.

You could either send post requests via Scrapy to retrieve the json response and then parse it.

Another option, since there is also a javascript variable with product data present in the page:
Load the `var thispageproduct` javascript variable present on the page into a python dictionary and then parse it.

```
class xxxx(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xxxx_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.decathlon.my/8548777-running-shoes']
    allowed_domains = ['xxxx.co.id']

    def parse(self, response):

        page_data = json.loads((response.xpath('//script').re_first('var thispageproduct = (.*?);')))

        for product_id in page_data.keys():
            product_data = page_data.get(product_id)

            yield {
                'name': product_data.get('name'),
                'price': product_data.get('price')
            }
```

Comment: woa, thanks mate. clear explanation.
so meaning that, is using post requests more powerful than response.css ? or depends on the page behaviour?

Comment: It depends on the behavior of the website. It is better to check to see if the page is being built by javascript. You can always check the response that Scrapy is receiving to make sure the data is present or not in the html.
In my experience, it is better to collect the data with Scrapy via an API if possible.
This means that you don't have to worry about css/xpath selectors, as the data is already represented in a structured format.
Last thing, if this answer helped, please mark it as a correct answer. Thanks